# Add confirm email address field registration Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is any way to add a confirm email address field on Wooocommerce registration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways... Simplest way is to add a new field to registration field and then validate the field when form submitted. Follow this....

1. Copy `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php` file over to your theme folder `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`
2. Add below code right under `*Email address` field.. if you have not edited the file yet.. then it's `line number 88` where after you have to put it...

[image: Woocommerce Regisration Form]

```
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="confirm_reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['confirm_email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['confirm_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
    </p>
```

3. Add Validation... Check if Email & Confirm Email is same value..

   ```
   function so_61352749_validate_confirm_email_register_field( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {

     // Confirm email is set but empty
     if ( !isset( $_POST['confirm_email'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Email is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
      }

      if ( isset( $_POST['confirm_email'] ) && $_POST['confirm_email'] !== $_POST['email'] ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'confirm_email_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Confirm Email is not matched!', 'woocommerce' ) );
      }

      return $validation_errors;
   }

   add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'so_61352749_validate_confirm_email_register_field', 10, 3 );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'codeithub_add_email_verification_field_checkout' );
   
function codeithub_add_email_verification_field_checkout( $fields ) {
  
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array( 'form-row-first' );
  
$fields['billing']['billing_em_ver'] = array(
    'label' => 'Confirm mail Address',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => array( 'form-row-last' ),
    'clear' => true,
    'priority' => 999,
);
  
return $fields;
}
  
  
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'codeithub_matching_email_addresses');
  
function codeithub_matching_email_addresses() { 
    $email1 = $_POST['billing_email'];
    $email2 = $_POST['billing_em_ver'];
    if ( $email2 !== $email1 ) {
        wc_add_notice( 'Your email addresses do not match', 'error' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the mail address in the billing. How to do this for new account creation?